# How to change the value of the input field of my form depending on the page I am in

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm currently building a website using Angular, HTML/CSS, this website is for a company which organizes sports events, here the sport in honor is the trialthon, and for this event you have several different stages.

So, on my home page, I have 5 image tags, one for each stage, on those tags, I have a click function, to make sure that when you click on the image, it sends you to a page with two forms, one to switch from one event to another, the other to choose the division

home page :

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="homePage">
        <div class="blocEvent">
            <iframe width="400" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5Ed1LFBZaBk?autoplay=1"
                title="Teaser Grand Prix Triathlon FF TRI 2023" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <div class="homeEventDate">5 stages</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocEvent">
            <img id="Frejus" src="../../../assets/img/event/frejus.jpg" (click)="redirect(861)"/>
            <div class="homeEventCity">Frejus</div>
            <div class="homeEventDate">13 March</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocEvent">
            <img id="Bordeaux"
                src="../../../assets/img/event/20220702-GRAND-PRIX-TRIATHLON-D1FEMMES-@ActivImages-F-BOUKLA-5.jpg" (click)="redirect(862)"/>
            <div class="homeEventCity">Bordeaux</div>
            <div class="homeEventDate">17 June</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocEvent">
            <img id="Metz" src="../../../assets/img/event/metz.jpg" (click)="redirect(863)"/>
            <div class="homeEventCity">Metz</div>
            <div class="homeEventDate">1-2 July</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocEvent">
            <img id="Quiberon"
                src="../../../assets/img/event/2022-08-04-tri-d1h-fftri-@f-boukla-activimages-9528-1.jpg" (click)="redirect(864)"/>
            <div class="homeEventCity">Quiberon</div>
            <div class="homeEventDate">2 September</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocEvent">
            <img id="SaintJeanDeMonts" src="../../../assets/img/event/st_jean.jpg" (click)="redirect(865)"/>
            <div class="homeEventCity">Saint-Jean-de-Monts</div>
            <div class="homeEventDate">9-10 September</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

forms page :

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="homePage">
    <div class="menusSelector">
      <div class="menuStage">
        <form action="#">
          <label for="stages">Choice of stage :</label>
          <select name="stages" id="stages">
            <option value="choiceOfStage">Choice of stage :</option>
            <option
              value="frejus"
              routerLink="event/861"
              (click)="redirect(861)"
            >
              Stage 1 - Fréjus
            </option>
            <option
              value="bordeaux"
              routerLink="event/862"
              (click)="redirect(862)"
            >
              Stage 2 - Bordeaux
            </option>
            <option value="metz" routerLink="event/863" (click)="redirect(863)">
              Stage 3 - Metz
            </option>
            <option
              value="quiberon"
              routerLink="event/864"
              (click)="redirect(864)"
            >
              Stage 4 - Quiberon
            </option>
            <option
              value="saint-jean-de-monts"
              routerLink="event/865"
              (click)="redirect(865)"
            >
              Stage 5 - Saint-Jean-de-Monts
            </option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="menuDivision">
        <form action="#">
          <label for="stages">Choice of divison :</label>
          <select name="divisions" id="divisions">
            <option value="choiceOfDivision">Choice of divison :</option>
            <option value="div1Man" routerLink="D1H">Division 1 Man</option>
            <option value="div1Wowen" routerLink="D1F">Division 1 Wowan</option>
            <option value="div3Man" routerLink="D3H">Division 3 Man</option>
            <option value="div3Wowen" routerLink="D3F">Division 3 Wowen</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

What I'm actually trying to do is, when you click on one specific image on the home page, the default value of my form will be the event you clicked on previously.

For exemple, if I clicked on the event "Frejus", the default value of my form will be "Stage 1 - Frejus"

Update :

does anyone know if on Angular, there is a way (a function?) to change the value of the field of our form according to parameters that we indicate?
I saw that on Angular, you can set the type of an attribute as "Form", can I use this here ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you can just add `[selected]` and then check for the appropriate condition. So you could modify the `<option>`:

```
<option value="saint-jean-de-monts"
        routerLink="event/865"
        [selected]="checkSelected()"
        (click)="redirect(865)">
```

And then you could add a function `checkSelected` that checks whether the option value is the selected one (that's up to you) and return true or false.

**Edit**

Regarding your question in the comments on how to access the `value` properties: I guess the easiest way would be to name each option and pass it to the function:

```
<option #opt1
        value="frejus"
        routerLink="event/861"
        [selected]="checkSelected(opt1)"
        (click)="redirect(861)">
```

Then you can access it in Typescript using:

```
checkSelected(t: any) {
    return t.value === "frejus"
}
```

Comment: How can I get the option value in my component ?

Comment: I added the answer, hope this helps.